# checking if the following grammar is LR(0) and LR(1)

Tags: parsing, compilation, grammar, lr-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
S -> A
A -> B | B[*]
B -> [AB]
AB -> *,AB | epsilon
```

S,A,B,AB are variables and [ ] , * are terminals

Is it:

1. LR(0)?
2. LR(1)?
   and how can I prove it?

Comment: Have you tried building the configurating sets? What did you find?

Comment: The easy way to prove that it's LR(1) is, as @templatetypedef suggests, building a parser. The parser only has 12 states, so it shouldn't be too challenging. While you're doing that, you'll find the conflict which prevents it from being LR(0).

Comment: @rici can you please explain what you mean by the conflict in LR(0)?

Comment: I'm talking about parser conflicts, in this case a shift/reduce conflict. Since an LR(0) parser cannot use lookahead to decide which action to take, a production like `N -> A | A b` leads to a conflict; after the `A` is recognised, the parser must decide whether to *reduce* using the first alternative or to *shift* using the second alternative. The reduce action decides that the `N` has been recognised; the shift action decides that `N` is not yet complete. An LR(1) parser could look at the next input symbol, which might or might not be an `a`, but an LR(0) parser cannot.

Comment: If that explanation seems unfamiliar, I'd suggest you (return to) the textbook on parsing theory from which that problem was taken.